# Why does my program stop working instead of checking the input and outputing the menu and continue working?

Tags: c++, debugging, project

I did a project called ATM and watched YouTube to do the basics of it.

Then I upgraded it and it worked (first version), but because it had a few bugs, I upgraded it again and fixed the errors.

But now it's not working anymore. It's supposed to ask for the account number and see if it is valid or not. If not then redo, but if yes then it should show a menu and let me do different stuff. But now, when it asks me for my account number, and when I type my account number in, the program just stops instead of showing the menu and continue working.

After a week, I still can't find out what went wrong.

Can anyone please check what’s wrong with the code?

[Here is my ATM Project](https://github.com/TriNguyen0901/ATM)

I am not even sure what function is related to this problem, but I think it's the `inputcheck()` function, which I think is at line 33. It might have something to do with `cin.clear()` and `cin.ignore()`. I am not sure. So the input will be the account, and the function should check if it's valid.

I used some trick to return 2 variables, and it will return the account and whether it is  valid. I tried to do some changes, but I don't think it’s any better. I tried a lot of things that I don't even remember. Please help me with this.

Comment: StackOverflow is a Q&A site, not a debugging service. You are expected to ask *specific* questions. You need to learn how to run your code inside a debugger so you can step through the code statement-by-statement in real-time and see exactly where and why its behavior differs from your expectations.

Comment: @RemyLebeau cue the "i ran it in debug but it doesnt say anything" - sigh.

Answer (score 0):

well you call `inputcheck(option)`

This is declared as returning an int, but it returns nothing, plus you ignore the return value even if there was one. I suspect this doesnt help

same with `inputcheck(amount)`

I assume you mean to pass option as a refernce so that inputchekc can update it

ie change it to

```
inputcheck(T &input){...}
```

the compiler is warning you about the lack of a return value - or should be.

and I have no idea why those are templates but thats a different question.

Comment: Hello! So after reading your answer, I still dont really get it. It would be so much better if you answer in a more visual way (with picture) or easier to understand way. Thanks! And also, why we add & in inputcheck(T &input)? Btw, they are template because the user might input a different type I think?